# Cross references updated by save

Tags: libreoffice

When using LibreOffice v6.0.6.2 on 64bit Ubuntu 18.04, I can create bibliography entries from document fine, but when I re-open the document after saving, the entries have all been updated in as much as all details except the short name and title are emptied/deleted and the short name becomes 'CITATION "{name}"' in both the table and the cross-references.

Has anyone else experienced this and moreover has anyone else discovered a workaround/fix?

What I failed to record is the fact that the document in which I edit the cross-references is in Windoze Word format - doh!!!

Comment: Please do not put SOLVED I'm the title. Please do not put the answer in the comments. "Your answer"window is there for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Methinks I've inadvertently discovered a solution myself - merely by maintaining a LibreOffice document (.odt) as the master and exporting (save as) in Windows Word format as and when the occasion demands. Thans for the pointer @user6186 - point taken.